# Formatar Hora GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Bom dia, possuo um campo no grid, que é preenchido do SQL um campo Time(7).

Ele aparece dessa forma no grid: 15:10:51.1000000

Porém gostaria que ele aparecesse desta forma: 15:10:51, e de todas as formas que tento, não da certo, tentei assim: DataFormatString="{0:hh: mm}", assim : DataFormatString="{0:t}"

Ou ele dá erro na cadeia de caracteres ou simplesmente ele não converte para o formato certo. Gostaria de saber a forma certa de converter na coluna no grid. Agradeço.

Nenhuma forma que tento dá certo, possui alguma maneira de configurar a hora do GridView ??

Comment: Não sei se funcionaria para você , mas eu uso tipo hora.ToString("HH:mm:ss"). Mas acho que não é seu caso.

Comment: Pois é William é porque eu configuro direto dentro do GridView. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o assim:

```
DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}"
```

O `HH` tem que ser Maiúscula

Exemplo:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="hora" HeaderText="Hora" SortExpression="Hora" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}" ShowHeader="True" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma Tiago, porém não funciona, estou configurando direto dentro do GridView. "<asp:BoundField DataField="hora" HeaderText="Hora" SortExpression="Hora" DataFormatString="HH:mm" ShowHeader="True" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>"

Comment: @marianac_costa veja isso te atende

Comment: Tiago tentei exatamente desta forma, e me retorna o seguinte erro: "Detalhes da Exceção: System.FormatException: Cadeia de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto." Já tentei com os segundos também,  me retorna o mesmo erro, quando tiro o DataFormatString ele funciona normal.

Comment: Tenta este formato `{0:HH/mm}`

Comment: Mesmo erro Tiago. Será que não consigo formatar a hora dentro do GridView